# json object with multiple json object within it

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json

I have some PHP that generates the a JSON object from data from a MySQL database

```
$addressData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM address WHERE ContactID = $contactID")or  die("<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($addressData)){
    $rows[] = array('data' => $r);
}

// now all the rows have been fetched, it can be encoded
echo json_encode($rows);
```

This generates the following JSON object:

```
[
  {"address":
    {"AddressID":"10011","AddressType":"Delivery","AddressLine1":"4 Caerleon Drive","AddressLine2":"Bittern","AddressLine3":"","CityTown":"Southampton","County":"Hampshire","PostCode":"SO19 5LF","Country":"United Kingdom","ContactID":"10011"}},
  {"address":
    {"AddressID":"10012","AddressType":"Home","AddressLine1":"526 Butts Road","AddressLine2":"Sholing","AddressLine3":"","CityTown":"Southampton","County":"Hampshire","PostCode":"SO19 1DJ","Country":"England","ContactID":"10011"}}
]
```

When receiving it back in Ajax and running it through the following:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  string =string + "Key: " + key + " Value:" + val + "<br />";
});
```

which prints the following:

> Key: 0 Value:[object Object]
>
> Key: 1 Value:[object Object]

Any ideas about how I can access the objects within key `0` and `1` in data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Object's default toString implementation results in "[object Object]" when concatenating to a String object. You can access the fields of the val object as usual, for example:

```
val.data.AddressID
```

like this:

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
  string += "Key: " + key + " Value:" + val.data.AddressID + "<br />";
});
```

Please note that val in the loop above is the {"data": ...} part of the JSON code, that is why you need to specify *val.data.* to access parts of the address data inside.

Also, you could simply remove the *data* nesting level, resulting in a JSON layout like that:

```
[
    {"AddressID":"10011","AddressType":"Delivery","AddressLine1":"4 Caerleon Drive","AddressLine2":"Bittern","AddressLine3":"","CityTown":"Southampton","County":"Hampshire","PostCode":"SO19 5LF","Country":"United Kingdom","ContactID":"10011"},
    {"AddressID":"10012","AddressType":"Home","AddressLine1":"526 Butts Road","AddressLine2":"Sholing","AddressLine3":"","CityTown":"Southampton","County":"Hampshire","PostCode":"SO19 1DJ","Country":"England","ContactID":"10011"}
]
```

Using this PHP code:

```
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($addressData)){
    $rows[] = $r;
}
```

And then, you could access the address data fields in the loop like this:

```
$.each(data, function(key, address) {
  string += "Key: " + key + " Value:" + address.AddressID + "<br />";
});
```

Comment: no because `val` is the {data: {}} object. he should change the format of his json and get rid of the data: nesting

Comment: Agree, the data field's nesting level is useless, I will add that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

i would change the layout of your json, you don't need the nesting. try:

```
[
    {"AddressID":"10011","AddressType":"Delivery",...},
]
```

then you can iterate the return value as an array with key => val where `val` will be the object, because right now, `val` is the object holding the object you want...

Comment: Good advice. Just change `$rows[] = array('data' => $r);` to `$rows[] = $r;` and your old code will work fine.